# JSR 336 - фитчер позволяющий выполнять switch на string

Tags: java, строки, switch

Есть такой не непосредственной связанный с программированием вопрос, а косвенный.

Допустим известно, что в 7 версии Java, в 336 документе JSR была введена возможность выполнять switch на стринги. Каким образом и где я могу увидеть, какая критика и сопротивление были этому нововведению ?

Есть такое где-то в этом документе JSR-описание ???

Вопрос на ориентацию и анализе выпусков и их составляющих. Может кто помочь, кто в таких данных разбирается ?

[Ссылка на источник](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074031/core-java/jdk-7--java-switching-on-strings-is-here.html)

[страничка детализации JSR #336](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=336)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSR 336 - это зонтичный проект, объединяющий множество JSR, вошедших в Java 7. Конкретно строки в switch реализовывали в рамках проекта [Project Coin](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/coin/).

Обсуждения велись в списке рассылки coin-dev, который уже архивирован. Порыться в архивах можно тут: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/

Comment: Интересно, а как найти конкретные записи связанные со свичером ? 
Даты я вижу по второй ссылке разбросанные, просто прйтись по всем записям и найти нужные мне записи, я так понимаю ?

Comment: Да, улучшений предлагалось много, поищите про switch.

Comment: Полагаю, можно скачать архив и просто поискать по содержимому файлов.